# c# TrimEnd removes more than needed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

Here is debugger.
I don't understand why TrimEnd delete 's' character.
[image: Before TrimEnd]
After TrimEnd()
[image: After TrimEnd]
Any suggestions?

recPath is private string in class.
code:

```
        recPath = "";
        recursiveFindPathRoot(node);
        string[] argv = Regex.Split(recPath, "\\\\");

        //Current root path
        string rootdat = argv[0];

        //Current lastkey
        string valdat = argv[argv.Length - 3];
        string lastkey = valdat + "\\\\";

        string[] val_dat =  Regex.Split( valdat , "--");

        //Getting value and data
        string value = val_dat[0];
        string data = val_dat[1];
        string caption = value;

        CollectDataInput("Please edit selected key", caption, out value, out data);

        recPath = recPath.TrimEnd(lastkey.ToCharArray());
        recPath = recPath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing in `lastkey.ToCharArray()` as the list of characters to trim. That includes the character `s`, so the `s` of `Fonts` is being trimmed as well. (Ditto the backslash.) From the docs for [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx):

> The TrimEnd method removes from the current string all trailing characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation stops when the first character that is not in trimChars is encountered at the end of the string.

You're expecting the characters to be used as a single string, I suspect.

If you just want to remove `lastKey` from the end of `recPath`, you can use:

```
if (recPath.EndsWith(lastKey))
{
    recPath = recPath.Substring(0, recPath.Length - lastKey.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN:

> The TrimEnd method removes from the current string all trailing
>   characters that are in the trimChars parameter.
>    The trim operation stops when the first character that is not in trimChars is encountered at the end of the string.

Basically, in your lastKey String you have the char '\' and the char 's', but don't have the 't'... so it removes the all the last chars and stops at the t of "Font".

TrimEnds doesn't remove a sequential order of chars. Use Substring (or LINQ) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You provided a string `logPixels--50\\\\`, after converted to char array it contains `s` and other characters.

Now `trimEnd` start finding these characters at end of your string and keep removing until it arrives to `t` of `font` which was not in array, where it stop working.